# explain using countifs with an additional condition

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$5:$B$36,"C620")+COUNTIF ($F$5:$F$36=$G$5:$G$36)
```

so if C620 and the number in cell F is equal to cell G it counts a 1.

Answer (score 0):

decided to go ahead with the following to resolve my issue

=SUMIF($B$5:$B$36,"C620",$G$5:$G$36) to count the total contents in the range associated with C620